# plsql batch blocked by forms screen

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms 6i application and there is a plsql batch and both are doing updates to the same table. There are fields that are directly mapped to table columns in a form of the Forms application. Whenever the form accessing the table is open, the plsql batch is blocked. How to create the form so that it does not block any other db sessions. Is there a way to load/create instance of the Form so that it does not hold any lock on the table?

Comment: Is `Locking Mode` property set to `delayed` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of 2 possibilities:

1) For block there is property "Locking Mode" and one of it's values is "Delayed". Text from help:

> Form Builder locks the row only while it posts the transaction to the database, not while the end user is editing the record.  Form Builder prevents the commit action from processing if values of the fields in the block have changed when the user causes a commit action.

So if this value is set, then DB record will be locked only on update time.

2) Create ON-LOCK trigger for this block, with "Execution Hierarchy" property - "Override" (this is default one). And in trigger put code:

```
NULL;
```

In this case form's will not lock record and it will be done by DB only when necessary (after UPDATE statement is issued and till COMMIT or ROLLBACK is processed).

Answer (score 0):

Forms locks the record only when a database-bound item is changed either by the user or by a trigger.

You probably have some WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE or POST-CHANGE triggers that changes the values of database-bound items.
Before messing with locking modes, you should take a look on what causes forms to request a row lock. I bet you will be surprised!

Try first to disable ALL WHEN & POST trigger at Block & Item level, and examine if the form still locks the batch. After that start by enabling triggers until you spot the one that causes the problem.